# How to convert SQL datetime date format into unix utc format?

Tags: php, sql, date

I have standart sql datetime format: `2016-10-24 14:26:53.000`
And i dont know how to convert into UTC format should be something like: `138853800000`
Can be done in sql or php.

I tried something like:

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', 2016-10-24, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $d->getTimestamp().'<br>';
```

I works but after i add hours minutes it stops

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: Where's the SQL? (That timestamp interval is as defined by ISO 8601.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my two cents :

```
$d = new dateTime("2016-10-24 14:26:53.000", new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
echo $d->getTimestamp();
```

Output :

> 1477319213

```
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u P');
```

output :

> 2016-10-24 14:26:53.000000 +00:00